# Need help resetting a javascript countdown timer

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown, jquery-countdown

So I am a web designer and I inherited a site from another developer. The site in question is for an annual event and features a countdown timer on the home page. I am still pretty new to js and could use some help resetting the timer to next years date of March 1st, 2019. I have posted the code for the count down timer below. Any advice would be much appreciated!

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.countdown = function(options, callback) {

        //custom 'this' selector
        thisEl = $(this);

        //array of custom settings
        var settings = { 
            'date': null,
            'format': null
        };

        //append the settings array to options
        if(options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        //main countdown function
        function countdown_proc() {

            eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;
            currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);

            if(eventDate <= currentDate) {
                callback.call(this);
                clearInterval(interval);
            }

            seconds = eventDate - currentDate;

            days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)); //calculate the number of days
            seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24; //update the seconds variable with no. of days removed

            hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
            seconds -= hours * 60 * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of hours removed

            minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            seconds -= minutes * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of minutes removed

            //conditional Ss
            if (days == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("day"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("days"); }
            if (hours == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hour"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hours"); }
            if (minutes == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minute"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minutes"); }
            if (seconds == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("second"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("seconds"); }

            //logic for the two_digits ON setting
            if(settings['format'] == "on") {
                days = (String(days).length >= 2) ? days : "0" + days;
                hours = (String(hours).length >= 2) ? hours : "0" + hours;
                minutes = (String(minutes).length >= 2) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
                seconds = (String(seconds).length >= 2) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
            }

            //update the countdown's html values.
            if(!isNaN(eventDate)) {
                thisEl.find(".days").text(days);
                thisEl.find(".hours").text(hours);
                thisEl.find(".minutes").text(minutes);
                thisEl.find(".seconds").text(seconds);
            } else { 
                alert("Invalid date. Here's an example: 12 Tuesday 2012 17:30:00");
                clearInterval(interval); 
            }
        }

        //run the function
        countdown_proc();

        //loop the function
        interval = setInterval(countdown_proc, 1000);

    }
}) (jQuery);
```

Comment: The function is not called here. You need to find where `countdown` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct a date via the `Date` object and then pass the date and a callback function to `countdown`

```
    const oneHourFromNow= new Date();

    oneHourFromNow.setHours(oneHourFromNow.getHours() + 1);

    const config = { 
                     "date": oneHourFromNow.toString(),
                     "format": "off"
                   }

    const callbackFunc = function() {console.log("Do something");}

    $.fn.countdown(config , callbackFunc );
```

```js
(function($) {
    let interval;
    
    $.fn.countdown = function(options, callback) {

        //custom 'this' selector
// I hard-coded this ***
        thisEl = $('#countdown-timer');

        //array of custom settings
        var settings = { 
            'date': null,
            'format': null
        };

        //append the settings array to options
        if(options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        //main countdown function
        function countdown_proc() {

            eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;
            currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);

            if(eventDate <= currentDate) {
                callback.call(this);
                clearInterval(interval);
            }

            seconds = eventDate - currentDate;

            days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)); //calculate the number of days
            seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24; //update the seconds variable with no. of days removed

            hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
            seconds -= hours * 60 * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of hours removed

            minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            seconds -= minutes * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of minutes removed
//console.log(thisEl, thisEl.find(".timeRefDays"));
            //conditional Ss
            if (days == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("day"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("days"); }
            if (hours == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hour"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hours"); }
            if (minutes == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minute"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minutes"); }
            if (seconds == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("second"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("seconds"); }

            //logic for the two_digits ON setting
            if(settings['format'] == "on") {
                days = (String(days).length >= 2) ? days : "0" + days;
                hours = (String(hours).length >= 2) ? hours : "0" + hours;
                minutes = (String(minutes).length >= 2) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
                seconds = (String(seconds).length >= 2) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
            }

            //update the countdown's html values.
            if(!isNaN(eventDate)) {
                thisEl.find(".days").text(days);
                thisEl.find(".hours").text(hours);
                thisEl.find(".minutes").text(minutes);
                thisEl.find(".seconds").text(seconds);
            } else { 
                alert("Invalid date. Here's an example: 12 Tuesday 2012 17:30:00");
                clearInterval(interval); 
            }
        }

        //run the function
        countdown_proc();

        //loop the function
        interval = setInterval(countdown_proc, 1000);
    }
    
    
    // here you can create your Date instance any way you like:
    const oneHourFromNow= new Date();

    oneHourFromNow.setHours(oneHourFromNow.getHours() + 1);
    
    const config = { 
                     "date": oneHourFromNow.toString(),
                     "format": "off"
                   }

    const callbackFunc = function() {console.log("Do something");}

    $.fn.countdown(config , callbackFunc );
    
    
}) (jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="countdown-timer">
  <span class="days"></span> <span class="timeRefDays"></span>
  <span class="hours"></span> <span class="timeRefHours"></span>
  <span class="minutes"></span> <span class="timeRefMinutes"></span>
  <span class="seconds"></span> <span class="timeRefSeconds"></span>
</div>
```